# Replacing IP with server name in fping output

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a txt with a list of IP that I would like to check using `fping`, and then translate IP into name.

My file (`hosts.txt`) looks like this:

> 192.168.1.1 serverA
>   192.168.1.2 serverB
>   192.168.1.3 serverC

and this is the script I have written:

```
#! /bin/bash
N_Hosts=$(wc hosts.txt | awk {'print $1'})

typeset Nodos[$N_Hosts]

i=0;  
while read line  
do  
 Nodos[$i]=$(echo $line | awk {'print $1'})  
 i=$i+1  
done < hosts.txt

comando="fping "
comandoCompleto=$comando${Nodos[*]}

$comandoCompleto | sed 's/is alive/OK/g' | sed 's/is unreachable/down/g'
```

Its output is like:

> 192.168.1.1 OK
>   192.168.1.2 down
>   192.168.1.3 OK

And I would like it to be:

> serverA OK
>   serverB down
>   serverC OK

Is it possible to change the output using `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: This line isn't doing what you think it's doing: `i=$i+1`. In the first iteration, `i=0`; in the 2nd iteration, `i=0+1`; 3rd , `i=0+1+1`. You're just doing string contatenation. Bash doesn't do math unless you use special syntax. Fortunately for you, bash does evaluate the stuff between brackets (in an array element assignment) as an arithmetic expression. For clarity, replace `i=$i+1` with `((i++))` or `let "i=$i+1"`.

Comment: In the bash manual, read about [shell arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic), [arithmetic substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) and `((...))` in [conditional constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two files, your hosts.txt and output.txt (output from script) then you can do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$1=a[$1]}1' hosts.txt output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks JS! I have created a temp file for the output, then awk both files, and remove the temp one

Answer (score 1):

Entirely in awk (I think this requires gawk)

```
gawk '
    { 
        name[$1] = $2 
        ips = ips " " $1
    }
    END {
        while ((("fping" ips) | getline) != 0) {
            if ($3 == "alive") 
                print name[$1] " OK"
            else if ($3 == "unreachable") 
                print name[$1] " down"
        } 
    }
' hosts.txt
```

or entirely with bash version 4

```
declare -a ips
declare -A names

while read ip name; do
    ips+=($ip)
    names[$ip]=$name
done < hosts.txt

fping "${ips[@]}" |
while read ip _ status; do
    case $status in
        alive) echo ${names[$ip]} OK ;;
        unreachable) echo ${names[$ip]} down ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks glenn, I have changed what you pointed out about i=$i+1! I'll take a deep look to your solution

Comment: If your getline encountered an error you'd get stuck in an infinite loop. Personally, I wouldn't try to do this all in awk, it's just not what it's good at (text manipulation).

Answer (score 1):

#### GNU sed

```
sed -r 's#(\S+)\s+(\S+)#/\1/s/(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)/\2 \\2/#' hosts.txt|sed -rf - output.txt
```

..output:

```
serverA OK
serverB down
serverC OK
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is:

```
while read ip name
do
    fping "$ip" |
    awk -v n="$name" '{print n, (/alive/?"OK":"down")}'
done < hosts.txt
```